# Enable older .Net versions on Windows 10 for specific user

Tags: c#, windows-10, settings, .net-framework-version

I have 2 executables as part of my software. One is built with .Net 3.5 and the other with .Net 4.5. Both combiningly make up the software. However they both will run in 2 different users (admin and non-admin user).

As specified in [this MSDN forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/how-to-enable-net-framework-35-on-windows-10/066ebeb2-1a05-40cd-916c-b7185f1d9939), Winodws 10 allows to enable older .Nets along with the latest .Net. However this way the older .Net gets enabled for all the users. I don't want to enable older .NET for non-admin users.

Is there a way to enable it only for the current user?

Comment: "One is built with .Net 3.5" - will it *run* on higher frameworks? most things usually will...

Comment: NO it doesn't. If i try to run it without enabling the older .net I get a popup from OS asking to enable the same. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10

Comment: Why don't you want to allow 3.5 for non-admin users? It won't stop them running 4.5 applications.

Comment: OK; and presumably this isn't your own tool (i.e. you can't just rebuild it for an up-to-date framework), and wherever it came from hasn't released an update? Sorry if I'm asking the obvious here, but .NET Framework 3.5 (SP1) is pretty ancient now (from 2008) - technically still in mainstream support until 2023, but... it really seems like the preferred solution here is to get an updated build

Comment: Enabling that, will enable all the older .Nets including .Net 1 and 2 as well. That seems unwanted and may lead to security risks

Comment: Upgrading isn't an option here due to legacy reasons.

Comment: @Sisir limiting the security risks to the **admin account** doesn't seem to mitigate against that at all (and no, I don't think that enables .NET 1.\*)

Comment: Sorry, but I think the answer to the actual question here is likely to be "no, that is not possible"

Comment: Yes, it does. I have verified and confirmed. The admin user is and internal user and is considered a service engineer and is the rare used user. So that's ok

Comment: @MarcGravell That would be disappointing. I would expect this settings to be customizable as per the user need.

Comment: "If i try to run it without enabling the older .net I get a popup from OS asking to enable the same...".  You *may* be able to get past this by adding a `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0">` element to your application configuration file

Comment: @Sisir You can make your app compatible with the latest .NET Installed by adding supported runtimes. This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5#to-configure-your-app-to-run-on-the-net-framework-4-or-later-versions) is what you need